# Flask authenticate with Sharepoint Online

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint, oauth-2.0, flask-oauthlib

I am trying to write a web service which uses some data from a Sharepoint Online site using the `flask_oauthlib` module.

I've set it up like this:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from . import settings
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(settings) # To get SECRET_KEY

from flask_oauthlib import OAuth
oauth = OAuth(app)

sharepoint = oauth.remote_app(
  'sharepoint',
  consumer_key = '<redacted>',
  consumer_secret = '<redacted>',
  request_token_params = {'scope': 'AllSites.Manage'},
  base_url = 'https://<redacted>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx',
  request_token_url = None,
  access_token_method = 'GET',
  access_token_url = 'https://<redacted>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx'
)

@sharepoint.tokengetter
def get_sharepoint_token(token=None):
  return session.get('sharepoint_token')

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return sharepoint.authorize(callback='https://localhost:5000/login')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
  resp = sharepoint.authorized_response()
  if resp is None:
    return 'Login failed: ' + request.args.get('error_description')
  session['sharepoint_token'] = ( resp['auth_token'], resp['auth_token_secret'] )
  session['sharepoint_user'] = resp['screen_name']
  return 'Hello, ' + resp['screen_name']

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True, ssl_context=('server.crt', 'server.key'))
```

This successfully redirects to a Sharepoint authorisation screen where I'm asked if I trust my app.  When I click the 'Trust It' button, I get an internal server error with this on the console:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Mar/2018 14:48:15] "GET /login?code=IAAAAJ2%5FBr9vn6qSXfgVMvTH8zRV7l%2DFvowYYRZ4jRO52i5u7RA%2DKwgdswowaS4Msg79Oz%2Dl70kgUvpSwE8VtzJ7cXlw8EEN5lR6znN6XgaGSJrdZoYLTkVQuXMlN%5FAVy1TTnNCe5R5TFqL1sm6kphH7PnvxZQ6IX...<redacted> HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/tkcook/git/azimuth-timesheets/timesheets/routes/__init__.py", line 15, in login
    resp = sharepoint.authorized_response()
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_oauthlib/client.py", line 677, in authorized_response
    data = self.handle_oauth2_response()
  File "/home/tkcook/Envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_oauthlib/client.py", line 664, in handle_oauth2_response
    type='invalid_response', data=data
flask_oauthlib.client.OAuthException: Invalid response from sharepoint
```

Poking into this, it looks like Sharepoint is returning HTTP 403 Forbidden.  I've tried this with client id/secret generated by registering an app in Azure AD and also with one generated by registering an app on the Sharepoint site collection (by going to `/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`) and with one generated by registering an app on a specific site (by going to `/sites/nameofmysite/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`).  All give the same result; the authorisation screen is displayed but then the last step gives HTTP 403.

What have I got wrong?

Comment: what is the value of data in `type='invalid_response', data=data`?

Comment: I'm the author of Flask-OAuthlib. Currently, I'm working on another lib, would you try with this one: https://github.com/lepture/authlib

Answer (score 0):

We can do authentication as below article

[SHAREPOINT ONLINE REMOTE AUTHENTICATION (AND DOC UPLOAD)](http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/)

And we can do operation via REST API.

[SharePoint REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)

Comment: This requires that you know the user's username and password.  I'm trying to authorise using OAuth, ie without the user's password.